# how can i update my phone to windows phone 10

Tags: windows-10

Recently I update my phone to Windows phone 8.1 beta(developer) version but until now I don't receive original version of Windows 8.1.
Now I don't want to update to Windows 10 preview version and revive original and main version of it(when it released).
So any on one know how can I done that?
Can I update my phone from 8.1 beta to 10 official?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, given the title "how can i update my phone to windows phone 10", and then your statement within your question "I don't want to update to Windows 10 preview version", which conflicts. Perhaps you could edit your question to better explain the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Windows 10 official isn't out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Only official Windows 7, 8, 8.1 (desktop versions of Windows) and Windows phone 8.1 can be upgraded to Windows 10. 
But as it was noted in the comments, Windows 10 is not officially released yet. 
So personally I would recommend you to install official version of Windows phone 8.1 using  [WindowsPhone recovery tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525569) or   [Lumia software recovery tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=525568)

Comment: For more information about free upgrading to Windows 10 you can visit http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/about